# Command-line ID3 tag editor that handles all tags

Tags: macos, command-line, mp3, script, id3

I am looking for a tool to edit tags in MP3s through a script.

The files are episodes of several podcasts where the tags are inconsistent between episode: Sometimes the Album or Genre tag is missing for example. The script will run after new episodes are downloaded to modify the tags.

I have tried id3tool and id3v2 already.

[id3v2](http://id3v2.sourceforge.net/) does not support free Genre tags, only a numbered list of predefined genres is offered. In this list, there is no genre "Podcast".

[id3tool](http://nekohako.xware.cx/id3tool/) only supports id3v1, where the field lengths are limited. But there is an option to specify free Genre definitions.

Is there a tool that supports all the required functionality?
It should compile under Mac OS X 10.6.

Comment: Someone had recommended eyeD3, but I don't know where this answer has gone. I have tried eyeD3 and it seems to do what I want. I will report after success.

Comment: Nowadays `id3v2` supports free genre tag: `id3v2 -g Podcast my.mp3`. It will be shown with code 255 (as all free tags): `TCON (Content type): Podcast (255)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use Homebrew:

```
brew install id3lib
```

Example command: ide3tag

```
Usage: id3tag [OPTIONS]... [FILES]...
   -h         --help            Print help and exit
   -V         --version         Print version and exit
   -1         --v1tag           Render only the id3v1 tag (default=off)
   -2         --v2tag           Render only the id3v2 tag (default=off)
   -aSTRING   --artist=STRING   Set the artist information
   -ASTRING   --album=STRING    Set the album title information
   -sSTRING   --song=STRING     Set the title information
   -cSTRING   --comment=STRING  Set the comment information
   -CSTRING   --desc=STRING     Set the comment description
   -ySTRING   --year=STRING     Set the year
   -tSTRING   --track=STRING    Set the track number
   -TSTRING   --total=STRING    Set the total number of tracks
   -gSHORT    --genre=SHORT     Set the genre
   -w         --warning         Turn on warnings (for debugging) (default=off)
   -n         --notice          Turn on notices (for debugging) (default=off)
```

Source: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/16145/53242

Answer (score 10):

The `mutagen` Python module comes with a `mid3v2` command.

```
mid3v2 --artist "Sigur Rós" *.mp3
```

---

Before you ask: No, `mutagen` does *not* support ID3v1, because there is *no* valid reason to be using it these days.

Comment: I don't want to use ID3v1, so your tip is alright.

Comment: Mutagen can be installed with `sudo easy_install pip; sudo pip install mutagen` on OS X. `mid3v2` also supports Unicode unlike `id3tag` and `id3v2`.

Comment: Note that `mutagen` forces everything to ID3v2.4 (in 2023), which doesn't have support on some older devices.

Comment: A valid reason would be my wife's car's car stereo only reading id3v1 tags when it displays the title of the currently playing track on a cd of burnt mp3s.... i mean, we can't all have fancy new cars all the time y'know

Answer (score 1):

[ID3 Editor](http://www.pa-software.com/products/overview.php?prod=BC3B2E3A)
Although the linked website page is oriented towards GUI, it does contain "NEW! Command line editor".

Comment: Tag is a Windows based command line tool or missing I something?

Comment: @relikd: You are right - so I edited it out.

Comment: [Pa-Software ID3 Editor](http://pa-software.com/id3editor/) is trialware or USD15 - not free

Comment: @MarkMikofski: This must have changed since 2010.

Answer (score 1):

[Tagr](http://www.entwicklungsfreu.de/tagr.html) was recommended; it's free, looks powerful (batch process, cover work, etc.), but not sure it has CLI.

Comment: It's not free. As of 2017-01-01 it's $9.99 on AppStore.